# i have a problem when filtering a list according to two dates in c#

Tags: c#, .net, linq, datetime

```
var result = myList.Where(t =>  t.ReportDate >= StartDate)
                   .Where(t =>  t.ReportDate <= EndDate)
```

I'm trying to get all objects in a list (`myList`) thats have date (`ReportDate`) between `StartDate` and `EndDate`... I used the above code it worked good but when `StartDate` and `EndDate` are equals it returns `null`. can anyone help... thanks in advance.

Comment: Does your end date value contain time portion?  mm/dd/yyyy 23:59:59 or is it just mm/dd/yyyy 00:00:00

Comment: Are you trying to filter by date or datetime?

Comment: @HamletHakobyan I am using `DateTime?`

Comment: The question was about your intent not about the data type you have used.

Comment: What you have expected to be returned when `StartDate == EndDate`?

Comment: when `StartDate == EndDate` i want to return the object tha have `ReportDate` same as the `StartDate `... when i am comparing the time portion is included

Comment: When `StartDate` and `EndDate` are equal the query logically boils down to `t.ReportDate == StartDate`. Obviously, that's nearly always false when time portions are in play.

Comment: so the problem is with the time portion... i tried to exclude time portion but it didn't worked with nullable `DateTime`

Comment: One small suggestion, use `&&` in one `Where` instead of two `Where`

Comment: @viveknuna: That won't make any semantic difference.

Comment: @JonSkeet I agree but it will look more readable and meaningful

Comment: @viveknuna: I think that's actually a matter of opinion - but I'd *at least* say that if you make a suggestion which you know won't fix the problem, it's worth making that clear when you suggest it. Otherwise it would be entirely reasonable for the OP to think you're suggesting a *solution*.

Comment: @JonSkeet sure, I’ll keep this in mind. Thank you 

Comment: I wonder why most answers focus on removing time portions. I think it's very simple. `StartDate` and `EndDate` just define a time interval between which results should lie. The only thing is that a time interval of 0 doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

It seems, that you want to *exclude* *time* component:

```
var result = myList
  .Where(t => t.ReportDate.Date >= StartDate.Date &&
              t.ReportDate.Date <= EndDate.Date);
```

If it's your case, then when `StartDate.Date == EndDate.Date` you'll get `result` with `ReportDate.Date == StartDate.Date`

Please, note, that often it's more convenient to *exclude* the `EndDate`:

```
var result = myList
  .Where(t => t.ReportDate.Date >= StartDate.Date &&
              t.ReportDate.Date < EndDate.Date);
```

For instance, if we want 2021 year we can put `1.1.2021 .. 1.1.2022` instead of `1.1.2021 .. 31.12.2021`

Answer (score 0):

I've done my best to incorporate your comments. This will ignore the time portion of the dates and will work with null ReportDates.

```
    DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
    // Get the Date part for the variables before the linq query
    DateTime startDate = now.Date;
    DateTime endDate = now.Date;
    
    List<Report> myList = new List<Report> { new Report(1, now), new Report(2, null), new Report(3, now.AddDays(1)) };

    // You are not required to make multiple Where calls
    // Check that ReportDate has a value before comparison
    // Get the Date part for the comparisons
    var reports = myList.Where(t => t.ReportDate.HasValue
                               && t.ReportDate.Value.Date >= startDate
                               && t.ReportDate.Value.Date <= endDate);
    
    foreach (var report in reports)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Report {report.ReportId}");
    }
```

> Report 1

Answer (score -1):

The following sample code might put you on the right track

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            List<DateTime> dateTimeList = new List<DateTime>
            {
                new DateTime(1946, 04, 11),
                new DateTime(1948, 04, 22),
                new DateTime(1975, 01, 23),
                new DateTime(1975, 01, 23),
                new DateTime(1977, 07, 07),
                new DateTime(1988, 05, 02),
            };
            DateTime beginDate = new DateTime(1970, 01, 01);
            DateTime endDate = new DateTime(1979, 12, 31);
            List<DateTime> result = dateTimeList.FindAll(x => x >= beginDate && x <= endDate);
            foreach (DateTime dateTime in result)
                Console.WriteLine(dateTime);
        }

    }
}
```